# Couldn't match expected type ‘Request’ with actual type ‘[Char]’

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I'm new to Haskel, I'm trying to run a simple example using `http-conduit`, the example is the one provided in their [documentation](https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md).

However, when running the program I always get:

```hs
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Request’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the first argument of ‘httpLBS’, namely
        ‘"http://httpbin.org/get"’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        response <- httpLBS "http://httpbin.org/get"
      In the expression:
        do response <- httpLBS "http://httpbin.org/get"
           putStrLn
             $ "The status code was: " ++ show (getResponseStatusCode response)
           print $ getResponseHeader "Content-Type" response
           L8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody response
   |
12 |     response <- httpLBS "http://httpbin.org/get"
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried to create a project both with cabal and stack, add `http-conduit` and `aeson` as dependencies, but still getting the error.

Shouldn't the url be implicitly converted to a `Request`?

I've tried to import `Request` and try to create a `Request` from the url, but it complains:

```
import Network.HTTP.Client.Request

<no location info>: error:
    Could not load module ‘Network.HTTP.Client.Request’
    it is a hidden module in the package ‘http-client-0.6.4.1’
```

Comment: I think that you'll get that error message if you somehow forgot to enable `OverloadedStrings`. The documentation you point to *does* include this, however, so it's not entirely clear why you'd get it. On the other hand, you don't write exactly how you try to run the program.

Comment: I was adding the LANGUAGE feature in the wrong place, a little bit more down and not at the top of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the [**`OverloadedStrings`** extension [schoolofhaskell]](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#overloadedstrings). You can add the `LANGUAGE` pragma to the top of the file, so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

-- …
```

This extension will implicitly add [**`fromString :: IsString a => String -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-String.html#v:fromString) to each string *literal* (not to be confused with an expression with *type* `String`). It makes it more convenient to work with string-like data such as for example [**`Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Text.html).

Beware however that the conversion is done at *runtime*, so if not all `String`s map to a (valid) `Request` object, then you will only see this when the `Request` is evaluated.

> Shouldn't the url be implicitly converted to a Request?

In Haskell, there are no implicit conversions, you always convert data through functions. The `OverloadedStrings` simply adds a implicit function call to the *literals*, and thus this means that a string literal now can take as type any type that is a member of the [**`IsString`** type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString).

Comment: Arg, stupid me, I had the LANGUAGE feature a little bit more down on the file, not at the very top. Thanks!. And thanks also for the detailed explanation.